# Create a fixed and dynamic header for a python dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am reading a gzip file and converting it to a Dataframe by the below method

```
   df = pd.read_csv(file.gz, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This actually populates the first row as column header. As the data in the gzip varies every time the column header also changes.Also there is no fixed column count it also differs as per file as below .

```
File 1 
        01-10-2019  Samsung    Owned
        -----------------------------
        01-10-2019  Samsung    Owned
        03-10-2019  Motorolla  Sold

File 2 
         SAMSUNG    Walmart    DHL    300$  Sold  Alaska
        --------------------------------------------------
        SAMSUNG    Walmart    DHL     300$  Sold  Alaska   
        Sony       Motorolla  Fedex   250$  Sold  Chicago
```

For me to do some data manipulation it would be great if I have a fixed column as 1,2,3 based on the no of columns the dataframe has like

```
 File 1 
            1            2         3
            -----------------------------
            01-10-2019  Samsung    Owned
            03-10-2019  Sony       Sold
File 2 
          1         2         3        4    5      6
        --------------------------------------------------
        SAMSUNG    Walmart    DHL     300$  Sold  Alaska   
        Sony       Motorolla  Fedex   250$  Sold  Chicago
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you don't want to read the header from the csv file.
That can be done using `header=None`.
If your csv file contain a header that you want to ignore, then you can also add `skiprows=1`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file.gz, compression='gzip', header=None, sep=',', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```